# Sorting a Big URL List for all Urls with "=" in Link & remove specific Domains

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

Im trying to sort a really big Url List. List contains 12 Mio Urls. Each Line 1 Url.
I want to filter all Urls with "=" (example.com/a.php?aaa=aaa) in a new File. 
After that i would love to remove Urls from Google, Bing, Facebook,etc.

How can i solve this? Im using Linux Terminal.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at grep‘s man page: `man grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this. First, copy all `URLs` with an `=` to a temporary file:

```
grep -e '=' /folder/file > /tmp/urlTempHolder
```

Then, delete any `URLs` that contain the domains you want to exclude:

```
sed -i -e '/google.com/Id; /bing.com/Id' /tmp/urlTempHolder
```

The answer will be stored on `/tmp/urlTempHolder`

**Note1**: make sure to include the top level domain `.com`, `.net`, etc. on your search to avoid deleting `URLs` that contain the keyword but should not be deleted (ex: `www.mydomain.com/stuff/bing/now.htm`).

**Note2**: the code above is case insensitive, thus it will match `BING.COM` as well as `bing.com`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep = urls.dat > urls-eq.dat
grep -v = urls.dat | egrep -v -i '\<(google|facebook|bing)\.(com|net)(/|$)' > urls-filtered.dat
```